# How to enable Shell Acess over HTTP/Web Browser?

Tags: linux, ssh, web-server, http, shell

I wish to grant Shell access over HTTP  (using a web browser) to a few of my users. Is there a utility, preferably free, which I may use to enable it.

The no. of users are approx. 100 and I want separate shell sessions for each of them, and the web interface should require them to login with their user/pwd credentials.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Ajaxterm](http://antony.lesuisse.org/software/ajaxterm/) is nice and reasonably simple to set up.

Comment: Are AnyTerm and AjaxTerm almost same or is there a major difference?

Comment: There's actually a comparison on the Ajaxterm page I linked.

Answer (score 2):

As I can't comment yet, I'll post this as an answer: Please make sure to setup https (SSL) if you use Ajaxterm for a SSH session. All the SSH-encryption won't be of any use if the traffic between your browser and the webserver isn't encrypted. You'll find a "Howto setup https" further down the Ajaxterm-page posted by Alex.

Answer (score 2):

The webmin suite (http://www.webmin.com/) has this (and far far more, if you're interested)

Comment: As long as an embedded shell is all Mohit is looking for, Webmin would be quite an overkill for this task.

Comment: +1 Matt, found Webmin a great tool for admin tasks.. thanks for inroducing me to it.
However, i find its nt a to-the-point solution for an embedded shell, the Java applet based shell is quite slow and clumsy. Thanks, anyways!

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is kind of old at this point but it is still showing up in lots of Google search results so I thought I'd provide an updated answer:

Gate One (HTML5 Terminal Emulator/SSH client):  http://liftoffsoftware.com/Products/GateOne
Gate One source code:  https://github.com/liftoff/GateOne/
...and here's a video overview if you like that sort of thing:  http://www.youtube.com/user/LiftoffSoftware

Gate One has many advantages over the other answers but this isn't the place to enumerate them.  Just see the links above for the details.

Full disclosure:  I am the author of Gate One.